# Copying files and folders to specific volume label

Tags: vbscript

I have a requirement to copy some files and folders to a USB drive with a specific volumelabel (to take into account drive letter may change)

I am using the below to determine, and return, the drive letter; how to I then use this to copy files to that drive (and overwrite any existing files)

I only know how to use objShell.run "cmd /c copy c:\temp\file.xml X:\temp file\ /y" but obviously can't use that in this case.

```
 Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colDrives = objFSO.Drives
For Each objDrive in colDrives

  Select Case objDrive.DriveType 
    Case 1
    If objDrive.VolumeName = "MyUSB" Then ' 
      Message = Message & "Drive letter: " & objDrive.DriveLetter & VbCrLf ' 
      Message = Message & "Drive type: " & objDrive.DriveType & VbCrLf '
      Message = Message & "Volume name: " & objDrive.VolumeName & VbCrLf & VbCrLf ' 
    End If
  End Select
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try for this example and tell me the result :

```
'Show drive letters associated with each
DriveLetter = ""
ComputerName = "."
Set wmiServices  = GetObject ( _
    "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!//" _
    & ComputerName)
' Get physical disk drive
Set wmiDiskDrives =  wmiServices.ExecQuery ( "SELECT Caption, DeviceID FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType = 'USB'")

For Each wmiDiskDrive In wmiDiskDrives
   ' x = wmiDiskDrive.Caption & Vbtab & " " & wmiDiskDrive.DeviceID 
    'Use the disk drive device id to
    ' find associated partition
    query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" & wmiDiskDrive.DeviceID & "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"    
    Set wmiDiskPartitions = wmiServices.ExecQuery(query)

    For Each wmiDiskPartition In wmiDiskPartitions
        'Use partition device id to find logical disk
        Set wmiLogicalDisks = wmiServices.ExecQuery ("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" _
             & wmiDiskPartition.DeviceID & "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition") 
x = ""
        For Each wmiLogicalDisk In wmiLogicalDisks
            'x = x & wmiDiskDrive.Caption & " " & wmiDiskPartition.DeviceID & " = " & wmiLogicalDisk.DeviceID
            'Wscript.echo x
            Wscript.echo "The DriveLetter of your USB Key is = " & wmiLogicalDisk.DeviceID & "\"
            DriveLetter = wmiLogicalDisk.DeviceID
        Next      
    Next
Next

Set WS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Command = "cmd /c copy c:\temp\file.xml " & DriveLetter & "\ /y"
wscript.echo Command
Result = ws.run(Command,0,False)
```

Or something like that :

```
Set Ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set FSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For each Drv in FSO.Drives
    If Drv.DriveType=0 Then Dtype="Unknown "
    If Drv.DriveType=1 Then Dtype="Removable"
    If Drv.DriveType=2 Then Dtype="Fixed "
    If Drv.DriveType=3 Then Dtype="Network "
    If Drv.DriveType=4 Then Dtype="CD-ROM "
    If Drv.DriveType=5 Then Dtype="RAM Disk "
    If Drv.IsReady Then
        If Drv.DriveType=1 Then
            Dfree=Drv.FreeSpace
            DfreeMB=FormatNumber(Drv.FreeSpace/(1024^2),0)&" MB"
            DriveLetter=Drv.DriveLetter
        End if
    End if
Next
MsgBox "Espace Libre dans Le Flash Disk " & DriveLetter & ":\"&" est Environ de " & DfreeMB,64,"Espace Libre"
Command = "cmd /c copy c:\temp\file.xml " & DriveLetter & ":\ /y"
wscript.echo Command
Result = ws.run(Command,0,True)
```